# Consume windows form events in C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, events, event-handling, c++-cli

How do I add an event handler method to, say a TextBox's TextChanged event ?

Comment: [Here's a HOWTO on the MSDN site.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kz5cx8k.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
void SomeClass::TextChanged_Handler(Object ^sender, EventArgs ^e){
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(L"Text changed.");
}

void SomeClass::RegisterHandler(){
    textBox->TextChanged += gcnew EventHandler(this, &SomeClass::TextChanged_Handler);
}
```

See examples for [EventArgs class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) on MSDN.